# Circular imports in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two classes in two files:

```
from Son import Son
class Mother:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sons = []
    def add_son(self, son: Son):
        self.sons.append(son)
```

and

```
from Mother import Mother
class Son:
    def __init__(self, mother: Mother):
        self.mother = mother
        mother.add_son(self)
```

Plus a main file

```
from Mother import Mother
from Son import Son
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mother = Mother()
    son1 = Son(mother)
    son2 = Son(mother)
```

Obviously, I have a circular dependency. How to deal with this kind of behaviour without losing the type hint stuff?

Comment: Article on [circular imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) here that may help.  Two solutions are to refactor code or move one import statement to end of the module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only circular dependency is in the type hints, and those can be specified as strings:

```
# Mother.py
class Mother:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sons = []
    def add_son(self, son: 'Son.Son'):
        self.sons.append(son)

# Son.py
class Son:
    def __init__(self, mother: 'Mother.Mother'):
        self.mother = mother
        mother.add_son(self)
```

You may still need to `import Mother` and `import Son`; I'm not sure whether current analysis tools are intelligent enough to resolve the type hints otherwise. *Don't* use `from` imports; those force resolution of the module contents at import time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have some interrogations. Let's imagine that instead of type hints, I need to import Mother to instantiate a new one. Would I have no other choice than refactoring? Also, does your "don't use from imports" mean never or avoid? Because with complex packages, referencing things may become quite messy, no?

Comment: @Vanesbush: Don't use `from` imports *here*. If you need to import `Mother` to instantiate a new one, again, don't use a `from` import. As long as you only resolve `Mother.Mother` once it's actually defined, you shouldn't encounter any errors, but you may still want to refactor.